# gapply sometimes returning duplicated groups?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, gapply

I'm running some code, the relevant essence of which is:

```
library(SparkR)
library(magrittr)
sqlContext %>% sql("select * from tmp") %>% 
  gapply("id", function(key, x) {
    data.frame(
      id = key,
      n = nrow(x)
    )
  }, schema = structType(
    structField("id", "integer"),
    structField("n", "integer")
  ))
```

Unfortunately, for some values of `id`, `nrow` has been calculated incorrectly. Compared to (on a subset of the data) running:

```
library(data.table)
tmp = sqlContext %>% sql('select * from tmp where id < 1000') %>% collect %>% setDT
```

And then running (where `gapply_df` is the `collect`ed result of the `gapply` command above):

```
gapply_df[tmp[ , .N, keyby = id], on = 'id'][N < n]
#      n   N
# 1: 276 138
# 2: 148  74
# 3: 122  61
# 4: 303 101
# 5: 266 133
```

I note that the `n` produced by `gapply` (`n` on the left) is sometimes a multiple (here 2x or 3x) of what is actually correct (`N` on the right).

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed? I'm worried that `nrow` is actually giving the right answer (it should be being called on a local `data.frame` after all), and that my data has been duplicated/triplicated, meaning the rest of my analysis could be wrong as well.

Sorry I can't provide a reproducible example; here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
# R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0
# locale:
# [1] C
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# other attached packages:
# [1] data.table_1.10.4 magrittr_1.5      knitr_1.16        SparkR_2.1.1     
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_3.4.1     markdown_0.8       tools_3.4.1
# [4] KernSmooth_2.23-15 stringi_1.1.5      highr_0.6
# [7] stringr_1.2.0      mime_0.5           evaluate_0.10.1
```

Running in `Zeppelin` with `spark` `2.1.1`.